# Counting categories based on date

Tags: vba, outlook

The code below does not count categories from specific day properly:

```vb
Sub HowManyEmails()
    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = Session.GetFolderFromID(Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.EntryID)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"
    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Dim oDate As String
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    oDate = InputBox("Date for count (Format D-M-YYYY")
    Set myItems = objFolder.Items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & oDate & "'")
    myItems.SetColumns ("Categories")
    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = myItem.Categories
        If Not dict.Exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem
    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        msg = msg & o & ":   " & dict(o) & vbCrLf
    Next
    MsgBox msg
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

When you write a date, the output is just categories and emails count which doesn't match the chosen date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format, valid for someone else, is likely not valid for you.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub HowManyEmails()

    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim EmailCount As Integer

    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim o As Variant

    Dim dateStr As String
    Dim myItems As items
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim msg As String
    Dim oDate As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    If err.number <> 0 Then
        err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Must closely follow an On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    EmailCount = objFolder.items.count
    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "email count"

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    ' oDate = InputBox("Date for count (Format D-M-YYYY")
    oDate = InputBox("Date for count (Format YYYY-m-d")

    Set myItems = objFolder.items.Restrict("[Received] >= '" & oDate & "'")

    ' myItems.SetColumns ("Categories") ' You will find this error due to On Error GoTo 0

    For Each myItem In myItems
        dateStr = myItem.Categories
        If Not dict.exists(dateStr) Then
            dict(dateStr) = 0
        End If
        dict(dateStr) = CLng(dict(dateStr)) + 1
    Next myItem

    msg = ""
    For Each o In dict.Keys
        If o = "" Then
            msg = msg & dict(o) & ":   " & "Not categorized" & vbCrLf
        Else
            msg = msg & dict(o) & ":   " & o & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox msg

ExitRoutine:
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set dict = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Well still when you select the date, it throws the message from day after too. I have looked into similar code and it works the same way, so I don't know if it can be fixed. Anyway, thank you @niton !

Comment: Or is it maybe possible to just read the categories only from today, without writing the date?

Comment: Is it that you do not understand the >= can be =? Set myItems = objFolder.items.Restrict("[Received] = '" & oDate & "'")